# Number of touch points on common/typical Android devices

Tags: android, multi-touch

What are the typical number of touch points supported by popular phone models? I've seen as low as 2 and as high as 5 in my basic research, but I'd like to be able to map this to actual mobiles and better limits!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709812/android-multitouch
and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067941/getting-the-number-of-touch-points-supported
should hopefully get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Touch point data of two phones:

```
Galaxy S       5
LG optimus     1
```